# SCeneKit handle tap gestures on each part of the 3D model

Tags: ios, iphone, scenekit

when i load node like

```
SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/ship.dae"];
```

how i can control taps on wings and each part of the plan as i want ? because handling tap gesture only allows me to get the node

```
// add a tap gesture recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
NSMutableArray *gestureRecognizers = [NSMutableArray array];
[gestureRecognizers addObject:tapGesture];
[gestureRecognizers addObjectsFromArray:scnView.gestureRecognizers];
scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers;
```

i want to add tap gesture to every part of the model , how i can do this